# Как разобраться с авторской пунктуацией и заменить её канонической?

Tags: авторская-пунктуация

> Мало кто из смертных знает, что такое «гастрольный график». Мало кто
>   способен такой жизненный ритм вообще выдерживать. Это почти ежедневные
>   переезды из города в город. И каждый вечер спектакль! А есть ещё и
>   съёмки. Это другое кочевое сообщество. У него иное устройство. **Ты на
>   день – неделю примыкаешь к этому организму и снова – и здесь ты в
>   игре.** Ты и живёшь свою жизнь, и становишься пусть ненадолго, но кем-то
>   другим. И когда в тебя стреляют «понарошку», ты действительно
>   представляешь себе эту боль, и ты падаешь. И ты умираешь. И ведь
>   нельзя сказать – притворяешься.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ты на день – неделю примыкаешь к этому организму и снова – и здесь ты
>   в игре.

Во-первых, **на день–неделю** - это предел, короткое тире (тире без пробелов). Во-вторых, **и снова – и здесь** как-то у меня в голове не укладывается. Может, что-то убрать?

*Ты на день–неделю примыкаешь к этому организму – и снова ты в игре.*

Answer (score 1):

> Ты на день – неделю примыкаешь к этому организму...

Право же, гораздо лучше смотрится *"на неделю-другую"*.